# Append referrer to query string

Tags: apache

I have a unique requirement. I want to read the value in the referrer header. And if the value has a particular string in it, I want to create a query string parameter and append this value to the query string before passing the request on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can do it using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). You want [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to check `%{HTTP_REFERER}` and then a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) making use of the `[QSA]` flag so the current query string is preserved and added to by what you specify in the substitution.